# Storybook component library sites?

Tags: storybook

If the point of storybook is to build reusable components, then where are all these reusable components? Locked away in private companies?

Shouldn't there be marketplaces/free collections of reusable components?

Do I just suck at googling?

Comment: I think this question doesn't suits SO, it may lead to opinion-based answers. Storybook is a "component explorer" ([as they say](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/get-started/examples)), the purpose isn't building reusable components, but it may be used for this. There are some component collections, marketplaces and libraries around (and some demos too), but it isn't the core of the team. I highly recommend checking their examples https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/get-started/examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of storybook is to provide teams/projects a way to develop/view/test their components in an isolated environment. It is a component catalog builder that use provided components to build himself.

See [an Intro to storybook](https://storybook.js.org/tutorials/intro-to-storybook/)

If you're asking for a reusable (free) components "marketplace" there's [bit.dev](https://bit.dev/) but its not related to storybook at all.